# Sitecore Folder tab error - The control ItemList has not been initialized

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce

Using `Sitecore 10.1` and sometimes getting the below error on **Folder tab**. Checked the log files and seeing this:

```
7644 08:38:39 ERROR Rendering of Folder.xaml.xml has been failed with exception: 'The control ItemList has not been initialized'
Exception: Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.ControlException
Message: The control ItemList has not been initialized
Source: Sitecore.Client
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Editors.Folder.FolderPage.Render()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Editors.Folder.FolderPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

[image]

Any idea why it's showing this error?

Comment: are you facing this after Sitecore upgrade or in vanilla instance of Sitecore 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing similar issues recently.

We have fixed the issue by restarting Sitecore Client and Server by restarting App server / locally you can kill sc related w3wp process.

We have checked what is called when you hit `Folder` tab and it is this:

[image]

We looked into this further by going to class `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Editors.Folder.FolderPage` in Sitecore.Client.dll and it's `Render` method:

[image]

We were wondering why the error was saying

> ItemList is not initialized

when clearly in xaml file itself Scrollbox with ID ItemList was initialized:

[image]